# Column cannot be null (MySQL and Hibernate)

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have a schema with column like below. Nulls are not allowed and default value is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. I am using hibernate to insert data into table with this column. However hibernate fails with below error. In my DAO, I am not setting any value for updateTime.

```
Error:
Column 'updateTime' cannot be null. 

Column Schema:
updateTime  timestamp CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you figure this out?  All of a sudden we are seeing the same issue.  We are wondering if it is an incompatibility with MySQL 5.6.

Comment: Grey, I also found out that issue was happening in MySQL 5.6. I downgraded to 5.5 and we do not see this issue any longer.

Comment: Fascinating @Thakur.  We _just_ had a similar problem with hibernate and 5.6 at work.  ORMLite should allow some mechanism to _not_ do an insert on a particular column.  That's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for me MySQL version 8.0

- MySQL column definition:

[image: Null table definition]

- Entity definition:

  ```
   @Basic(optional = false)
   @Column(name = "date_created", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   private Date dateCreated;
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` option to your column definition to archieve something like this:

```
updateTime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

You can do it using following DDL query:

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` MODIFY updateTime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

or just drop and recreate your table.

In a case with `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` option `updateTime` column will be automatically populated during insert by MySQL server. See [this entry of official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html) for more details.